# Malloc / Calloc crashing on the second interaction

Tags: c, struct, dynamic, malloc, calloc

I have a program that should return an array of pointers to students that I have in memory.
The first time my program works as it should, the second time it runs (there is a 3 time loop where I call the action), I get a crash without any explanation from the compiler. I would really appreciate an explanation as to why this is happening.

```
Student **getMyStudentBySize(Student *allStudent, int wantSize,
                             int maxsize, Teacher *pteacher) {      
    int counter = 0;
        
    Student **myStudent = (Student **)malloc(1 * sizeof(Student *));
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TOTAL_STUDENT; i++) {
        for (int h = 0; h < NUMBER_OF_CLASSES; h++) {
            if (allStudent[i].myClassRoom) {
                if (strcmp(allStudent[i].myTeachers[h]->name,
                           (char *)pteacher->name) == 0) {
                    myStudent[counter++] = &allStudent[i];
                    break;
                }
            } else
                break;
        }
    }
    return myStudent;
}
```

I am calling to the function here: (And this program is called from another function that calls it 3 times)

```
void assignTeacher(Teacher **teacherArray, ClassRoom **allClassRooms,
                   Student *allStudents) {
    int mySize = helperAssignTeacher(allStudents, *teacherArray, NULL);
    Student **myStudentFor = getMyStudentBySize(allStudents, mySize,
                                 allClassRooms[chooseClassRoom - 1]->maxSize,
                                 ((*teacherArray) + (chooseTeacher - 1)));
    printAllStudent(myStudentFor, allClassRooms[chooseClassRoom - 1]->maxSize);
}
```

the error message:

[image]

It appears in the second interaction

```
Student **myStudent = (Student **)malloc(1 * sizeof(Student *));
```

Comment: `malloc(1 * sizeof(Student*))` you only allocate space for *one* entry and then proceed to set more than one entry. If that isn't the problem or you need further help then you need to provide more complete code (you have not even shown any `calloc` calls yet your title implies you have some). So please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: I changed it to "Student $$myStudent =(Student$$) malloc(maxsize * sizeof(Student*));" but I want to send 3 times a student ** "array" that i did in Dynamic way, is it pussible?

Comment: No idea what "send 3 times a student" means. Please provide complete code as a [mre] that illustrates what you are trying to do.

Comment: My code is too long for me to send the whole thing,
But in the end this structure should have a class (ClassRoom) which contains an array of pointers for students present in the class,
I am supposed to return to the class the students who belong to a certain teacher.
At the moment I have 3 classes, this means that this operation will repeat itself 3 times (and will return me a set of students suitable for a new teacher each time)

Comment: There is the word "minimal" in that. Please read the link. Not asking for a full dump of your code. In fact, we don't want that. Reduce your code to just the smallest relevant parts that is still complete and can show the issue. Describing code in words is almost always unclear. We need to see actual code.

Answer (score 1):

You allocate an array of pointer with a length of `1` instead of `MAX_TOTAL_STUDENT`. You have undefined behavior because of a buffer overflow. The code may appear to work if storing entries beyond the end of the array does not have an immediate adverse effect, but the next call to `malloc` causes a segmentation fault presumably because the memory allocation data have been corrupted.

It is unclear what the `wantSize` and `maxsize` arguments mean since you iterate over `MAX_TOTAL_STUDENT` entries in all cases.

Here is modified version:

```
Student **getMyStudentBySize(Student *allStudent, int wantSize,
                             int maxsize, Teacher *pteacher) {      
    int counter = 0;
        
    Student **myStudent = calloc(MAX_TOTAL_STUDENT, sizeof(*myStudent));
    if (!myStudent)
        return NULL;
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_TOTAL_STUDENT; i++) {
        for (int h = 0; h < NUMBER_OF_CLASSES; h++) {
            if (allStudent[i].myClassRoom) {
                if (strcmp(allStudent[i].myTeachers[h]->name,
                           (char *)pteacher->name) == 0) {
                    myStudent[counter++] = &allStudent[i];
                    break;
                }
            } else
                break;
        }
    }
    return myStudent;
}
```

Comment: Hey mate, you right, but my code is still crashing the the second times of lines  *Student **myStudent = calloc(MAX_TOTAL_STUDENT, sizeof(*myStudent));

Comment: @Bubi: if you get a crash calling `calloc`, it indicates some memory corruption. The bug is probably somewhere else, in code you did not post. Post a minimal complete compilable program that shows the problem.